# Could two arrays be labeled as a single queue?

Tags: java, data-structures, queue, priority-queue

Would two arrays one with a data item and the other with an int (denoting its priority) be called a queue as data is added to the back and removed from the front? Both arrays are technically independent of each other although they do have corresponding values.

Comment: It wouldn’t be my preferred design. It’s certainly possible.

Answer (score 4):

This is software, and in software almost everything is possible.

But seriously: *queue* is simply an **abstraction**; it is a container that has certain properties. How such a concept is *implemented* ... is up to the implementer. So, when you find a way to use two arrays to *implement* the behavior that one would expect from a *queue*; sure why not.

But: then this implementation belongs **together**. You don't have two independent arrays then any more. If you make those arrays the implementation of your queue, than that is what they are; and nothing else! You would only be using them in that context (and best: as private members of your queue class); and nobody else outside should know about them; or have access to them.

And, of course: arrays have a **fixed** size; something that you might (or might not!) expect from a *queue*. On the other hand: if there would be a need for a "dynamic" queue; you could still use arrays; you just have to "grow" them, too when their capacity is reached.